# how does a server retrieve a website when a domain is visited from the browser

Tags: dns, get, html, put

Whenever I have interviews I keep getting these questions asked to me. Where if a user clicks a link on a browser or when a domain is typed into the browser, what exactly takes place and how the data is retrieved and renders the webpage on the users computer. What books  would help me on this?

Comment: Here's [one very detailed answer](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/3-how-does-the-internet-work/).

Comment: thanks, is there a book you can also recommend that I can read and it will give me more details so that I can better explain my knowledge?

Comment: Well, any book that deals with web technologies just have to explain `HTTP Request Response cycle` in some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good book that I had some hand in is [The TCP/IP Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159327047X). It's a little dated (it's from 2005), but the basic ideas haven't changed. He also has a [web site](http://www.tcpipguide.com/).